# Magento 2 nginx configuration loading default html docroot and not set docroot

Tags: nginx, magento, magento2, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux-2

My ngnix install is loading the default page from `/usr/share/nginx/html;` shown in `nginx.conf` under **Server** directive even though I have replaced, commented out the original with `/var/www/example_com/html;`

Am I missing something, do I need to set a **`symlink`** `/usr/share/nginx/html ->  /var/www/example_com/html` to get to load or add a **location** directive? This appears to be a nginx issue over a Magento 2.x but I thought I'd mention just in case.

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/example_com.conf**

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server { 

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
#   root /var/www/example_com/html;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example_com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;   
    index index.html index.phtml index.php;

### Loading Magento 2 nginx config ###

    include /var/www/example_com/html/nginx.conf.sample; #Mage2 
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

}
```

**/etc/nginx.conf**

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root    /var/www/example_com/html;


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

**nginx -T results**

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
    #server_name    _;
        #server_name  example.com www.example.com;
        #root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root    /var/www/example_com/html;


        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}


# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                                        html htm shtml;
    text/css                                         css;
    text/xml                                         xml;
    image/gif                                        gif;
    image/jpeg                                       jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                           js;
    application/atom+xml                             atom;
    application/rss+xml                              rss;

    text/mathml                                      mml;
    text/plain                                       txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor                 jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                                 wml;
    text/x-component                                 htc;

    image/png                                        png;
    image/svg+xml                                    svg svgz;
    image/tiff                                       tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                               wbmp;
    image/webp                                       webp;
    image/x-icon                                     ico;
    image/x-jng                                      jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                                   bmp;

    font/woff                                        woff;
    font/woff2                                       woff2;

    application/java-archive                         jar war ear;
    application/json                                 json;
    application/mac-binhex40                         hqx;
    application/msword                               doc;
    application/pdf                                  pdf;
    application/postscript                           ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                                  rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl                    m3u8;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml             kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz                 kmz;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                         xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject                    eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                    ppt;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics      odg;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation  odp;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet   ods;
    application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text          odt;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
                                                     pptx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
                                                     xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                                                     docx;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                         wmlc;
    application/x-7z-compressed                      7z;
    application/x-cocoa                              cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff                  jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file                     jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                           run;
    application/x-perl                               pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                              prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed                     rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager             rpm;
    application/x-sea                                sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash                    swf;
    application/x-stuffit                            sit;
    application/x-tcl                                tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert                       der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                          xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                            xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                             xspf;
    application/zip                                  zip;

    application/octet-stream                         bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                         deb;
    application/octet-stream                         dmg;
    application/octet-stream                         iso img;
    application/octet-stream                         msi msp msm;

    audio/midi                                       mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                                       mp3;
    audio/ogg                                        ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                                      m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                                ra;

    video/3gpp                                       3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                                       ts;
    video/mp4                                        mp4;
    video/mpeg                                       mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                                  mov;
    video/webm                                       webm;
    video/x-flv                                      flv;
    video/x-m4v                                      m4v;
    video/x-mng                                      mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                                   asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                                   wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                                  avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/magento_es_auth.conf:
server {

    listen 8080;
    location /_cluster/health {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3135/_cluster/health;
    }

}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf:
# PHP-FPM FastCGI server
# network or unix domain socket configuration

upstream php-fpm {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/example_com.conf:
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server { 

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

#root /var/www/example_com/html;
    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/example_com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;   
    index index.html index.phtml index.php;

### Loading Magento 2 nginx config ###

    include /var/www/example_com/html/nginx.conf.sample;
    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";

}

# configuration file /var/www/example_com/html/nginx.conf.sample:
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/default.d/php.conf:
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
# See conf.d/php-fpm.conf for socket configuration
#
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.(php|phar)(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.(?:php|phar))(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
}
```

**ngnix -V**
do I need to change `--prefix=/usr/share/nginx`?

```
sudo nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.20.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS  21 Apr 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx
.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/clien
t_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/ngin
x/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=ngi
nx --with-compat --with-debug --with-file-aio --with-google_perftools_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with
-http_dav_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_ima
ge_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --wit
h-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_
module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stre
am_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-threads --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-pr
otector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-op
t='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
```

Comment: Could you show us current nginx config using `nginx -T` command? I suppose, this behavior caused by some `root` directive. Any symlinking between web-server root directories can cause more problems, especially for other users, I do not recommend.

Comment: @user973254 added the results for nginx -t everything checking out as fine.  not sure where else to look that would have `/usr/share/nginx/html` as an overriding `root` path

Comment: I wrote `nginx -T` with uppercase `T`, it should dump your current nginx configuration, lowercase `t` just tests your config syntax.

Comment: @user973254 updated with correct parameter

Comment: config you've posted looks pretty normal to me, according to all related manuals, let's see what is in `access.log` and `error.log` after default page request

Comment: @user973254 I just posted my nginx  `--prefix` do I need to change that or should the ngnix config files override that with `root`

Comment: `--prefix` deals nothing with your `root` configuration directive. It is system configuration option, per-compilation part. Watch your logs.

Comment: @user973254 the access log is empty and the error.log has a bind error `[emerg] 20548#20548: bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
[emerg] 20548#20548: still could not bind()` this was already fixed.

Comment: you've made a request and `access.log` is empty? Don't you think it's strange, something is not right. Did you change your nginx config, did you re-load nginx after that?

Comment: yes nginx was reload, prior access logs have data. would disabling SELinux and Firewalld cause this root issue? I had it enabled and it made command line request really slow on AWS EC2 (Lightsail). That was the reason for the reboot/reset. (by the way thanks for helping me).

Comment: I don't think SELinux or any firewall has something to deal with nginx `root` directive handling